# why does this code throw a seg fault in assembly

Tags: nasm

When compiled and ran this piece of assembly code throws a Segmentation fault which I can't figure out

```
section .data

section .bss            ; Uninitialized data
        x resb 5

section .text
        global _start   ; entry point for linker (ld)

_start:
        ; Grab input from user
        mov eax, 3      ; system call number (sys_read)
        mov ebx, 2
        mov ecx, x
        mov edx, 5      ; 5 bytes 1 for the sign 4 for the numbers

        ;Output the number entered
        mov eax, 4      ; system call number (sys_write)
        mov ebx, 1
        mov ecx, x
        mov edx, 5

        int 0x80        ; kernel call
```

The goal is to declare a number inside the code and then output the value to the screen

Answer (score 0):

looks like I forgot to do the kernel calls that is why it results in a segfault

```
section .data


section .bss            ; Uninitialized data
        x resb 5


section .text
        global _start   ; entry point for linker (ld)


_start:
        ; Grab input from user
        mov eax, 3      ; system call number (sys_read)
        mov ebx, 2
        mov ecx, x
        mov edx, 5      ; 5 bytes 1 for the sign 4 for the numbers
        int 0x80        ; kernel call 

        ;Output the number entered
        mov eax, 4      ; system call number (sys_write)
        mov ebx, 1
        mov ecx, x
        mov edx, 5
        int 0x80        ; kernel call

        ; return 0 
        mov eax, 1
        mov ebx, 0
        int 80h         ; kernel call
```